# Elmah.axd with a Catch-all route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, elmah

I have the following route configurations:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");

routes.MapRoutes(); // Register Attribute Based Routes which the current assembly contains

routes.MapRoute(
    "404",
    "{*url}",
    new { controller = MVC.Error.Name, action = "CatchAllUnmappedRoutes", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = MVC.Student.Name, action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The "404" controller is being called when I navigate to Elmah.axd. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your web.config do you have this allowRemoteAccess turned on?

```
 <elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
 </elmah>
```

and this inside the section group

```
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" 
type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
```

also check that you have this handler defined

```
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" 
preCondition="integratedMode" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

or this one depending on which version of IIS you are running

```
    <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" 
type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
```

One more thing I would definitely try and I feel ashamed to say "Have you tried clearing your cache!" as this one has bitten me once whilst using chrome

Comment: I can still see the elmah page, but that controller is getting executed.

Comment: what happens if you comment the 404 route?